# Different ways to measure sets?

Tags: cantor-set

This is a pretty easy question but what are some common ways (or uncommon ways) to measure certain properties of sets?

I already know about Minkowski Dimension, Lebesgue Measure, and Hausdorff Dimension. What are some other ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is just one example of the notion of a measure of a set. Other measures include the counting measure, Haar measure, Liousville measure, etc. An analogy might be that the Lebesgue measure is to the Euclidean norm as the notion of a measure is to the notion of a metric. That is, a measure is a function (from a sigma algebra to the real numbers) which satisfies certain desirable properties of "size".

Comment: There are also less quantitative "small set" notions, such as first category sets, $\sigma-$porous sets, and small angle sets.